# How to use CSI.exe script argument

Tags: c#, scripting, csi

When you run csi.exe /? (with Visual Studio 2015 update 2 installed), you will get the following syntax

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 1.2.0.51106
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: csi [option] ... [script-file.csx] [script-argument] ...
```

I am just wondering how I can pass this [**script-argument**] into my csx script file. Let's say, my csx script (c:\temp\a.csx) has only 2 line as follows

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} !", <argument_from_commandLine>);
```

What I expect is after I run the following command line

```
csi.exe c:\temp\a.csx David
```

I will get

```
Hello David !
```

But I just do not know what I should do in my script file so I can pass the csi.exe [**script_argument**] to my script file (to replace ).

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Please consider marking the top answer as accepted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a global variable in scripts called `Args` which has these "script argument" values. The closest thing I can find to documentation is mention of it in [pull requests for the roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5857). In a csx file (test.csx):

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", Args[0]);
```

using the command line:

```
csi.exe test.csx arg1
```

will give the output:

> Hello arg1!

An alternative approach using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` could be made to work, but the problem is that this picks up all the arguments passed to csi process. Then you have to separate the "script arguments" from the options for csi itself. This work can be avoided by using the builtin Args variable which is going to be more maintainable as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I actually tried this method, but unfortunately, I used args[0], i.e. not capitalized Args[0], thus I got error "The name 'args' does not exist in the current context". Thanks a lot @mike.

Comment: @jyao: I've just tested this and `Args[0]` works exactly as @mikez describes.

Comment: @mikez Cool, looks great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` for that.

Example for your example:

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2]);
```

Notice that I'm reading the *third* item, because `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` gives the entire command line (if you run the script using `csi test.csx David`, the first one will be `csi` and the second one `test.csx`)

Comment: Thanks @zdimension, it looks like a solution.

Comment: While this might work for simple cases, if you are expecting to pass multiple reference or lib options to csi then the index won't be 2 (or even consistent between runs). There is a more direct way to access the script arguments as I show in my answer.