# How to access command line arguments in .csx script?

Tags: c#, c#-interactive, csi

I'm using `csi.exe` the C# Interactive Compiler to run a `.csx` script. How can I access any command line arguments supplied to my script?

```
csi script.csx 2000
```

---

If you're not familiar with csi.exe, here's the usage message:

```
>csi /?
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 1.3.1.60616
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: csi [option] ... [script-file.csx] [script-argument] ...

Executes script-file.csx if specified, otherwise launches an interactive REPL (Read Eval Print Loop).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CSI.exe script argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060860/how-to-use-csi-exe-script-argument)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns `["csi", "script.csx", "2000"]` for that example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061368/429091 avoids the issues with trying to guess where arguments intended for the script start, so I would not recommend the method in this answer

Answer (score 12):

CSI has an [`Args` global which parses out the arguments for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061368/429091). For most cases, this will get you the arguments you wanted as if you were accessing `argv` in a C/C++ program or `args` in the C# `Main()` signature `static void Main(string[] args)`.

`Args` has a type of [`IList<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than `string[]`. So you will use [`.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_1_Count) to find the number of arguments instead of `.Length`.

Here is some example usage:

```cs
#!/usr/bin/env csi
Console.WriteLine($"There are {Args.Count} args: {string.Join(", ", Args.Select(arg => $"“{arg}”"))}");
```

And some example invocations:

```
ohnob@DESKTOP-RC0QNSG MSYS ~/AppData/Local/Temp
$ ./blah.csx
There are 0 args:

ohnob@DESKTOP-RC0QNSG MSYS ~/AppData/Local/Temp
$ ./blah.csx hi, these are args.
There are 4 args: “hi,”, “these”, “are”, “args.”

ohnob@DESKTOP-RC0QNSG MSYS ~/AppData/Local/Temp
$ ./blah.csx 'hi, this is one arg.'
There are 1 args: “hi, this is one arg.”
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script:

```
    var t = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    foreach (var i in t)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

To pass in arguments to csx:

```
    scriptcs hello.csx -- arg1 arg2 argx
```

Prints out:

```
    hello.csx
    --
    arg1
    arg2
    argx
```

Key is '--' between csx and script arguments.

Comment: @binki this should be its own answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk I have promoted it to an answer and removed my comment. Thanks!